# jquery check empty element and remove

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p></p>
<p>1</p>
<p></p>
```

How to remove the element that doesn't contain anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) function like so :

```
$('p').filter(function(){
   return ( $(this).text() == "" )
}).remove();
```

Or using [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) :

```
$('p').each(function (i, e) {
 if ($(e).text() === "") $(e).remove();
});
```

More better by using [`:empty`](https://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) selector :

```
$('p:empty').remove();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/g43n9cn4/) - Inspect element(chrome) to view final output

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it like this:

```
$('p')
    .filter(function() {
        return $.trim($(this).text()) === '' && $(this).children().length == 0
    })
    .remove()
```